# Make {page-style} a synonym of {header-footer}

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

Customizing the header and footer of documents consists of two tasks which are closely intertwined:

- Choosing the default page style (e.g. `empty`, `plain` and `headings`) and choosing the page style for "special" (e.g. chapter-starting) pages. This is normally done using the commands `\pagestyle` and `\thispagestyle`. Some classes also provide macros for "special" page styles (e.g. `KOMA-script`'s `\chapterpagestyle`).
- Customizing the chosen page styles, especially `headings`. This is done either using the commands `\markboth` and `\markright`, or with the help of the packages `fancyhdr` or `scrpage2`.

At the moment, there are 77 questions tagged with [header-footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/header-footer), 26 questions tagged with [page-style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/page-style) and no questions tagged with [markboth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/markboth) or [markright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/markright). Looking at all those questions, it seems that [header-footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/header-footer) is used as sort of a general tag, i.e. also for questions that involve page styles:

- [How to remove header on the page with big picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13307/how-to-remove-header-on-the-page-with-big-picture)
- [How to change the position of the page number in the first page of every chapter of a book?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4332/how-to-change-the-position-of-the-page-number-in-the-first-page-of-every-chapter)

On the other hand, [page-style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/page-style) is sometimes used for questions that don't involve page styles (or headers and footers) at all:

- [The same height of text in a large document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15218/the-same-height-of-text-in-a-large-document)
- [Changing the paper size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7469/changing-the-paper-size)

I propose that, after skimming through the questions tagged with [page-style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/page-style) and retagging them when appropriate, [page-style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/page-style) should be made a synonym of the more general [header-footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/header-footer) tag, and existing questions should be merged.

Comment: Just to say that: I myself would find this a bit confusing (if I got it right that it means typing the tag "page-style" then yields "header-footer" on the post).

Comment: @Hendrik: Yes, you got it right, and yes, it would have to be explained in the tag wiki excerpt of {header-footer}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As about two weeks have passed and my proposal has gained some upvotes, I will start skimming through the questions tagged with [page-style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/page-style) and retagging those which don't involve page styles or headers and footers at all. After that, [page-style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/page-style) may be made a synonym of [header-footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/header-footer).

Here's my proposal for the "unified" [header-footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/header-footer) tag wiki excerpt:

> {header-footer} is about customizing
>   the header and footer of documents.
>   This involves choosing the appropriate
>   page style for certain pages (e.g.
>   *empty*, *plain*, *headings*) and (for the page styles employed) placing
>   information like the current
>   chapter/section title and page number.
>   Popular packages are {fancyhdr} and
>   {scrpage2}.

EDIT: I have finishing skimming and (where appropriate) retagging questions tagged with [page-style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/page-style). There are 20 such questions left; 12 of them already feature the [header-footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/header-footer) tag in addition to [page-style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/page-style). The tag wiki excerpts have also been updated (i.e. in case of [page-style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/page-style) changed to a notice that this tag should no longer be used). I now ask a moderator to make [page-style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/page-style) a synonym of [header-footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/header-footer) and to merge the existing questions.